# Numpy syntax for linear equation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I'm new to numpy but not python.  Have a question about the `numpy` way to do this, consider:

**Edit** : correcting the function**

```
def _my_function(weights, features, bias):
    # the pure python way
    value = 0.
    for i in range(len(weights)):
         value += (weights[i]*features[i])

    return value+bias
```

What is the numpy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `weigths` and `features` are numpy arrays of the same size, you can do elementwise multiplication:

```
values = np.sum(weights * features + bias)
```

If you want to avoid adding bias to each element of the product array, you can do

```
values = np.sum(weights * features) + bias * weights.size
```

You could even use Python's builtin `sum` function:

```
values = sum(weights * features + bias)
```

or

```
values = sum(weights * features) + bias * weights.size
```

The reason this works is that the expressions `weights * features` and `weights * features + bias` are both temporary numpy arrays, which are iterable along their first dimension and can therefore be passed to `sum`.

**Timing**

I ran the following timing tests in IPython:

```
%timeit weights.dot(features)
The slowest run took 145.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 649 ns per loop

%timeit np.sum(weights * features)
The slowest run took 17.09 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.83 µs per loop
```

Using `ndarray.dot` is on the order of five times faster than using `np.sum` on the product. However, the warning indicates that this may not be true the first time you run the code. 0.649µs * 145.86 = 94.66µs, while 2.83µs * 17.09 = 48.36µs.

Comment: This answer is correct and good also, but the top answer had more detail at one point, including complexity solution

Comment: I don't disagree with `dot` being the better solution here, but what do you mean by "complexity solution"?

Comment: I had added a comment about which the approaches would perform better

Comment: @SamHammamy. I added some actual timing infomation. Didn't know you wanted that.

Comment: Thanks! That's a much better and more thorough explanation!

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1:** Using `dot-product` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
weights.dot(features) + bias*len(weights)
```

**Approach #2:** Bringing in [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to perform the `sum-reduction` -

```
np.einsum('i,i->',weights,features) + bias*len(weights)
```

I would think approach #1 would be the better one.

Comment: sorry, I got the equation wrong in my first post.  Does you answer change based on the edit?

Comment: Where do you see matrix multiplication?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry I meant `dot-product` there. Edited.

Comment: My mistake. Vote flipped.